# How to build multiple linux kernel module with multiple source files in a single Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to build a set of Linux kernel modules with multiple source files:

```
obj-m += mst_pciconf.o mst_pci.o
mst-objs += nnt_device.o nnt_dma.o nnt_pci_conf_access.o \
            nnt_pci_conf_access_no_vsec.o nnt_memory_access.o \
            nnt_ioctl.o mst_pciconf_bc.o mst_pci_bc.o
```

The kernel modules will be mst_pciconf and mst_pci.
Seems 'mst-objs' is not the correct type.

Thanks all.

Comment: Which object files are for mst_pciconf, and which are for mst_pci? You need `mst_pciconf-y := foo.o bar.o`, `mst_pci-y := baz.o quux.o`, etc.

Comment: `-objs` is for user space tools, should not be used for kernel modules.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify "-y" or "-m" (not "-obj") for every of your modules.
Example from net/wireless:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_CFG80211) += cfg80211.o
cfg80211-y += core.o sysfs.o radiotap.o util.o reg.o scan.o nl80211.o
cfg80211-y += mlme.o ibss.o sme.o chan.o ethtool.o mesh.o ap.o trace.o ocb.o
cfg80211-y += pmsr.o
cfg80211-$(CONFIG_OF) += of.o
cfg80211-$(CONFIG_CFG80211_DEBUGFS) += debugfs.o
cfg80211-$(CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT) += wext-compat.o wext-sme.o
```

where every $(CONFIG_XXX) expands to n/m/y from .config

So, in your case it would be something like that:

```
mst_pciconf-y += nnt_device.o nnt_dma.o nnt_pci_conf_access.o \
            nnt_pci_conf_access_no_vsec.o nnt_memory_access.o \
            nnt_ioctl.o mst_pciconf_bc.o mst_pci_bc.o
mst_pci-y += ...
```